# Remark to moderator as edit

Tags: discussion, edits

I just saw this question:
[Interpreting a benchmark in C, Clojure, Python, Ruby, Scala and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641098/i-made-a-little-math-benchmark-in-c-clojure-python-ruby-scala-and-some-other)

and currently it ends with:

> **Request to moderators:**
>
> (This is a third party edit) This question will be obviously closed
>   because it does not fit SO's target for questions (it's already being
>   voted for closure). Could any moderator move it to "Programmers"
>   instead of just closing it? Thanks!

I didn't specifically think this question needed closing until I read this, so this seems kinda a self-fulfilling profecy.

Personally I don't think this belongs in the question: a remark to a moderator should go in a flag, and everyone should make up their own minds about if something needs to be closed. You might want to put something in a comment if something needs discussing on a meta level (though I guess meta is better for that, I mean the name and all), but putting it in the question seems wrong.

I didn't want to go all edit-war on this because I'm not sure about how what where.. thoughts? should we discurage (and so remove) edits or remarks like these?

Comment: About the question itself: I kinda think that it's ok for SO, but that's not really the issue for me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only text in the question box should be that pertaining to the question itself. Anything else is just a distraction and misuse of features. Cleaning up a question is a pre-requisite for any migration, so it *can't* (or shouldn't) migrate with a message like that in it. In a month's time seeing that there is going to look odd wherever the question ends up.

There is a comment box for comments (e.g. clarification, suggestions etc.). There is a flag box for alerting moderators.

On a related note I also dislike edits that insert things like `**EDIT:**`. Edits should modify the question in a way that makes sense, the edits can be viewed from the revision history. The "edit summary" field can be used to summarise edits.

I took the liberty to make these edits (and improve the title) on this question - I don't think there's anything controversial here about keeping a question a question and an answer an answer. I've also raised a flag pointing to the message in the edit I removed. I'm not sure what a moderator will do based on that though, but it avoids the possibility of being accused of "losing" something important.